# Connected tree decomposition

Tags: graph-theory

Does every simple graph have a connected tree decomposition? A connected tree decomposition is a tree decomposition in which all the subgraphs induced by the bags(parts) are connected. I think the answer is yes since the connected tree-width concept has already been defined in graph theory. Since it's the minimum tree-width of all connected tree decompositions, I think the answer is yes unless we have 'unbounded' connected tree-widths as well.

Comment: Apologies if I’m missing something, but how would the subgraph induced by a tree not be connected?

Comment: @templatetypedef Well, the parts are not necessarily trees. We can give counterexamples of them not being trees.

Comment: Perhaps I’m confused about what a tree decomposition is. Are you partitioning the edges of the graph into trees? If so, wouldn’t each tree be connected?

Comment: @templatetypedef This is the definition of a tree decomposition of a graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition

Comment: @templatetypedef You can also find the definition on page 351 of Graph Theory by Reinhard Diestel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but this is not so interesting: let the bags be the connected components of the graph, and the tree structure on the bags an arbitrary tree.